# Command line arguments to wolframscript interact strangely with -file option

Tags: scripting, command-line

In order to avoid script-defined command-line arguments clashing with existing arguments to `wolframscript`, it appears you are supposed to use the `--` (or equivalently `-args`). This works exactly as expected with the `-code` option:

```
> wolframscript -c 'Print[$ScriptCommandLine]' -- -foo 7 -bar 8 -baz 9

{wolframscript, -c, Print[$ScriptCommandLine], --, -foo, 7, -bar, 8, -baz, 9}
Null
```

Now let's create a file that does the same thing.

```
> echo 'Print[$ScriptCommandLine]' > test.m

> wolframscript -f test.m -- -foo 7 -bar 8 -baz 9
{test.m}
```

There's no trailing `Null`, which seems helpful, but all the arguments also vanish, which is **not** helpful.

FWIW, this seems to suffice as a workaround, but it's a pretty annoying one:

```
> wolframscript -c 'Get["test.m"]' -- -foo 7 -bar 8 -baz 9
{wolframscript, -c, Get["test.m"], --, -foo, 7, -bar, 8, -baz, 9}
Null
```

All of this is with Mathematica 11.3.0 on Mac OS X.

Comment: `wolfram  -script  test.m  --  -foo 7  -bar 8  -baz 9`